# MySQL/Hibernate : Default value for not-null column does not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a 
null or transient value
```

I am using Java,Hibernate and MySQL 5.1.52-log version.

My interpretation of default is if I don't supply value for the column, Hibernate will insert the default value when I try to save this object.

HBM file,

```
<property name="isActive" type="java.lang.Short">
        <column name="IsActive" not-null="true" default="1"/>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of PropertyValueException, if you set a null value in a property declared not-null="true" and then try to persist/update it, then you will get this exception.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/PropertyValueException.html

You should remove the not-null="true" attribute from the config (because the default value of not-null is false) and then the database should insert the default value that you specified in the configuration for you (in this case '1').

**[UPDATE]**

I would have preferred to put this as a comment in fujy's answer but I am not allowed to comment on other answers yet. Does it work as expected if you remove the 'not-null' attribute (As I am showing below)? I believe that is what is causing the exception that you are getting.

```
 <property name="isActive" type="java.lang.Short">
     <meta attribute="default-value">1</meta>
     <column name="IsActive" />
 </property>
```

Comment: I recommend you to read fujy's answer first since I've never used hibernate xml configuration before. I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set it on your model directly

```
 private Short isActive = 1;
```

Or you could try this in your `hbm` file

```
 <property name="isActive" type="java.lang.Short">
     <meta attribute="default-value">1</meta>
     <column name="IsActive" not-null="true"/>
 </property>
```

Comment: Do you have any annotations ( or other settings ) on `isActive` field?

Comment: Nope, I am not using annotations instead I am using HBM file. and I mentioned in my original post how I have defined the 'isActive' field.