# Setting default value of Database if value is null

Tags: java, hibernate

In java hibernate how to set the default value from the database in column if the value inseting is null using hibernate hbm property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624627/mysql-hibernate-default-value-for-not-null-column-does-not-work

Comment: But this is not working when i try to enter the default value only the null value is entering into the table

Answer (score 0):

For .hbm files you can use,default element
Ex:-

```
<column name="age" not-null="true" default="18"/>
```

Comment: this didn't work by i think not-null is used to set the column as not null